# Create and update in the same sequelize transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, transactions, sequelize.js

I want to insert a new row and immediately update it, all within the same sequelize transaction, is this possible?

My code so far:

```js
let transaction;
    
try {
    transaction = await dbcontext.sequelize.transaction();
    
    const newRole = await dbcontext.Role.create({
          name: "New Role"
    }, { transaction });
    
    await dbcontext.Role.update(
          {
            name: "New name",
          },
          {
            where: {
              id: newRole.id,
            },
          }, { transaction }
    );
    await transaction.commit();
    console.log("Role commited");
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Rollback in progress");
    if (transaction) {
          await transaction.rollback();
    }
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, that is why I'm asking if it's possible to do an insert and update in the same transaction.

Comment: What is the aim? Is it achieving more than entering the second name directly?

Comment: Yes, this is the reduced version, actually what I am looking for is to update a field of all the rows, but first I need to create the rows if they do not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` has only two parameters so the `transaction` option should be indicated right next to the `where` option:

```js
await dbcontext.Role.update(
          {
            name: "New name",
          },
          {
            where: {
              id: newRole.id,
            },
            transaction,
          }
    );
```